# VS code analyzing again and again -- FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am using flutter with VS code because it is very lightweight and simple as compared to other IDE But for many days. flutter is analyzing again and again. Sometimes never-ending analyzing until I restart the IDE. The analyzing also make the vs code much slower which makes a disturbance in coding... Am very upset because my PC is just 8 GB of ram, Can not handle Android studio, as well as I like the vs code very much. If you guys have any idea about this then share.

Answer (score 2):

Follow that 3 instruction:

1. Delete flutter SDK and install again

2.Delete Flutter plugin

3.Update Vscode(Recommended)